# Disable wordpress caching of styles using "ver" url parameter

Tags: wordpress

After every link that is enqueued in php using wp_enqueue_style, wordpress automatically inserts `?ver=` and the wordpress version number. For example `.../style.css?ver=4.4.2`

In chrome this makes it almost impossible sometimes to refresh the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to remove :**
Add the below to your functions.php file

```
// Remove WP Version From Styles    
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );
// Remove WP Version From Scripts
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );

// Function to remove version numbers
function sdt_remove_ver_css_js( $src ) {
    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
```

**For Custom Version**
Version number is a parameter of `wp_enqueue_style()`.

Per the Codex, here are all the parameters that wp_enqueue_style accepts.

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

So for example to load a stylesheet with a version number you'd do the following:

```
function wpa_90820() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/my-styles.css', '', '1.0' );   

}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_90820');
```

Comment: The reason I avoided the enqueue method was because I'd have to do it for every style. Using a filter just applies it to all of them automatically.
But I wasn't aware of remove_query_arg. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this one by adding a filter on the style loader hook that replaces the version number with the current time value. Works a treat, but not to be used in production!

```
// TODO Remove this once put in a production environment
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'development_disable_style_caching');
function development_disable_style_caching($tag){
  return str_replace(get_bloginfo('version'), time(), $tag);
}
```